# blank query rejection using argv[0] in perl

Tags: perl, argv

I'm trying to make the script exit when a blank query is entered.  From what I've read, this code should work fine, but doesn't seem to want to, because "" isn't numeric.  What is the workaround?

```
if(($#ARGV < 0) || ($ARGV[0] == "")){
  print "$0: Enter a query.\n";
  exit 1;
}
```

To clarify,

```
perl run.pl "query"
```

should work, while

```
perl run.pl ""
```

should prompt for a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if(($#ARGV < 0) || ($ARGV[0] eq "")){
  print "$0: Enter a query.\n";
  exit 1;
}
```

`eq` for string comparison.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Coming from python, this was unexpected.

Comment: Or even just `if ( !length $ARGV[0] ) { ...`

Comment: Or `if (grep /\S/, @ARGV)`